# Flash transparent background animation issue in Google Chrome

Tags: wordpress, flash, cross-browser

I am working on wordpress project i have embed a flash player it's working in Fire Fox,Opera, IE9 + IE10 but in Google Chrome animation not working.If any body have any idea how to sort out this issue let me know.

```
<link href="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" />

<!--[if !IE 10]><html id="ie10" <?php language_attributes(); ?><![endif]-->


<div class="main-content flash" style="float: left; width: 100%;" align="center">

<a style="margin-left: -48px; text-decoration: none;" href="home-2"><img alt="" src="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/images/enter1.png" width="216" height="62" /></a>
<div class="main-intro" style="border-radius: 10px;">
<div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
<div class="fottext" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 36%; text-align: center; width: 100%;"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="how-bandit-buster-works"><strong style="color: red;"><span style="font-size: xx-large;"> "BANDIT BUSTER SECURITY SYSTEM"</span> </strong></a>
<strong style="color: red;"><span style="font-size: x-large;"> "IF YOU CAN'T SEE IT, SOMEONE CAN AND WILL STEAL IT"</span> </strong></div>

<object id="FlashID" style="border-radius: 10px;" width="1100" height="480" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">


<param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent"   /><param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" /><param name="expressinstall" value="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/Scripts/expressInstall.swf" /><param name="src" value="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/intro7.swf" />
<embed src="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/intro7.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"width="1100" height="480" name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> 
</embed> 
</object >

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand `FlashID2`, `FlashID3`, etc... And why are you using SWFObject *at the same time* with an `<object><embed>` block?

Comment: From Chrome console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < banditbuster.com/:6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Below code working for flash embed animation with transparent background for  IE9 +10 ,firefox,chrome,opera browser's.**

```
<!--[if IE 10]><html id="ie10" <?php language_attributes(); ?><![endif]-->
<!--[if firefox]><html id="firefox" <?php language_attributes(); ?><![endif]-->
<!--[if ! chrome]><html id="chrome" <?php language_attributes(); ?><![endif]-->
 <object id="FlashID" style="border-radius: 10px;" width="1100" height="480" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" /><param name="expressinstall" value="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/Scripts/expressInstall.swf" /><param name="src" value="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/intro7.swf" />
 <embed id="FlashID" src="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/intro7.swf" wmode="transparent"  quality="high" width="1100" height="480" name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>
     </embed> 
     </object >
    <!--[if firefox]>
    <embed id="FlashID" src="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/intro7.swf" wmode="transparent"  quality="high" width="1100" height="480" name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>
    </embed> 
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In your source code you have an unclosed tag...

```
<script type="text/javascript"  href="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" </script>
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript"  href="http://banditbuster.com/wp-content/themes/banditbuster/Scripts/swfobject_modified.js"></script>
```

Comment: for which line you are talking about

Comment: your code is not working i got the solution now its working good.

Comment: You still need to close that tag though

Comment: See my new posted answer and which line of code you talking about i don't understand will you elaborate it.